# How to determine if GTK widget has been destroyed

Tags: c, gtk, widget

I have some `Gtk+` code written in `C` that does some animation using `Cairo` and a timer. Most of the time when I click on the close application icon I get the following message on the terminal:

> Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_queue_draw: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET
>   (widget)' failed

Now I'm assuming this is happing because at the moment I close the application the timer is fired and the main window widget is accessed but has since been destroyed. What is the usual method to determine if a Gtk widget is still valid and can be referenced?

The offending code is here:

```
gboolean rotate_cb( void *degrees )
{
    rotation += DegreesToRadians((*(int*)(degrees)));
    // Tell our window that it should repaint itself (ie. emit an expose event)
    /* need to only call gtk_widget_queue_draw() if window is still valid / exists */
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(window);
    return( TRUE );
}
```

I'm assuming there must be some way to test whether or not `window` is still active and valid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is quite subtle. This usually happens because of the rules of ownership and destruction of GObject/GtkObject. Let me remind them:

- `GObject`s are simply count referenced. They are destroyed when the count reaches 0. A newly created object has count 1.
- `GInitiallyUnowned`s are also count referenced, and they are also destroyed when the count reaches 0. But a newly created object has a *floating count*. That means that the first time the count is to be incremented it is not actually incremented, but the floating count is *sunk*, that is, converted to a normal reference.

`GtkObject`s **are** `GInitiallyUnowned` objects, so they have the magic *floating count*.

But you probably know all this... Now, my question:

> Who owns the counter of the visible main GtkWindow?

That's actually easy, the GTK framework has a list of these and retains a reference of every visible `GtkWindow`. But then, another question:

> When does the GTK framework free the references of its GtkWindow?

Do you remember the `gtk_widget_destroy()` function and the `destroy` signal? They are exactly for that: when you want to remove a toplevel `GtkWindow` you call `gtk_widget_destroy()`, it activates the signal `destroy`, that is received by the GTK framework that removes the actual window and frees its reference to the object.

And here comes the reason for your problem: if the GTK framework retains the only existing reference to the `GtkWindow`, the object is actually freed. If then, your timer tries to access to it, it will fail, because the window is no more.

And here, at last, comes (hopefully) the solution:

- Call `g_object_ref()/g_object_ref_sink()` on the window when you start the timer. Also register a handler to the `destroy` signal of the window.
- In the handler of the `destroy` signal of the window: call `g_object_unref()` on the window and stop the timer.

Naturally, this partial solution should also work, because the window will not be destroyed without sending the `destroy` signal:

- Register a handler to the `destroy` signal of the window.
- In the handler of the `destroy` signal of the window: stop the timer.

But it is considered a good practice to increment the ref-counter of the objects when you are actually keeping a pointer to them.

Comment: Thank you rodrigo for your very detailed response. I learned a lot and appreciate it.

Comment: A very educative answer, +1!

Answer (score 3):

There is no way, because you'd query state of object that's no longer in memory, i.e. of some undefined chunk of memory.  Such a function could fail e.g. if there is another widget created at the same memory address.  In principle, you could just use that `GTK_IS_WIDGET()` macro, but is *not guaranteed* to work correctly even if most often it will.

The correct way to solve your problem is instead remove the `rotate_cb()` callback when `window` gets destroyed.  There is "destroy" signal in `GtkWidget` class for that.  So, you should connect to "destroy" and in that handler remove `rotate_cb()` (or set some flag that makes `rotate_cb()` do nothing).

Answer (score 3):

`g_object_weak_ref()` is also usefull for these cases

> Weak references are used for notification when an object is finalized.

You can connect a weak ref callback (by ex. `widget_destroy_cb`) to disconnect `rotate_cb` from widget before it gets destroyed, so `rotate_cb` should not be called once the widget gets destroyed.